# Disable to add new files in some folder

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I need to prevent new files to be added to my folder into my hosting. I use wordpress and i need to disable to add new files into some folders. In need custom `htaccess`? I use this code in `wp-content` folder, but i need some to disable any new file in, for example, `themes` folder or `wp-include` folder.

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
<Files ~ ".(xml|css|jpe?g|png|gif|js)$">
Allow from all
</Files>
```

I find this code to block new files into wp-include folder

```
# Block the include-only files.
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^wp-admin/includes/ - [F,L]
RewriteRule !^wp-includes/ - [S=3]
RewriteRule ^wp-includes/[^/]+.php$ - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^wp-includes/js/tinymce/langs/.+.php - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^wp-includes/theme-compat/ - [F,L]
```

Someone to expain me this lines? I want to block include any new files in wp-include and subfolder. This code do that? Thanks

Comment: why dont you set permissions for the folder?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Anoop, can you suggest me some permission to do that? Remember, this is wordpress folders. Thanks again